# How to increment value in Master table column with number of records in Details table in performant and accurate way?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-performance, update, count

I am using SQL Server 2008 and above.

I have following two tables:

```
MasterTable
MId
DetailsCount DEFAULT 0

DetailsTable
DId
MId
```

In `MasterTable.DetailsCount`, I store number of records in `DetailsTable` with matching `MId`.

Record is inserted in Master table first and then many thousands of records are inserted in Details table for given MId. This happens on multiple threads. Each thread has its own `SqlConnection`.
Total records in Details table are millions and increasing.

On `DetailsTable.MId` column, non-clustered index is added. Clustered index cannot be added.

I have tried two ways to maintain `DetailsCount` column:

1. Scan Details table to get the count
   After inserting in Details table, update the `DetailsCount` using query:

```
UPDATE MasterTable
SET DetailsCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DetailsTable WHERE MId = ?)
WHERE MId = ?
```

Due to millions of records in details table, this way is not performant as I need to scan Details table (to get count) each time new record is added in it. It is not performant even with the non-clustered index. If we simply comment the updation of that column, we see much increase in performance.

2. Increment count in Master table
   After inserting in Details table, update the `DetailsCount` using query:

```
UPDATE MasterTable
SET DetailsCount = DetailsCount + 1
WHERE MId = ?
```

This way is better as I do not need to access Details table.
But, the insertion in Details table happens over multiple threads. Each thread uses different `SqlConnection` instance.
That is why, `DetailsCount` often get updated with incorrect value.

I had a look at [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16), but I think it only works on single table; not Master-Details table.

I am looking for performant way to maintain the `DetailsCount` column with accuracy.

Comment: For performance the + shall be faster, however data integrity is also very important i guess

Answer (score 5):

I would encourage you not to implement this design at all.

The count of *detail* records has no business being in the *master* table. It represents a data duplication and a potential source of anomalies when the count doesn't match the number of detail records. The count is derived data and should be calculated on demand, as needed to satisfy a *read* request:

```
SELECT 
    MT.MId
    DetailCount =
    (
        SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
        FROM Details AS D
        WHERE D.MId = MT.MId
    )
FROM MasterTable AS MT
WHERE 
    MT.Mid = {?};
```

You should focus on a good and correct relational design first and only worry about performance if you can *prove* there is an actual problem that cannot be resolved any other way than by duplication.

Millions of detail rows are nothing. A b-tree index on the MId column of the details table will make computing the count on demand very fast indeed.

The only update execution plan with runtime statistics you provided has now been deleted. It ran for zero milliseconds and showed a look up of a non-existent master record that didn't access the detail table anyway. Not very informative.

[image: Plan]

The question lacks necessary detail, but it seems likely any poor performance you see is *caused* by the (unnecessary) update and blocking when multiple threads try to update the same master record after every detail row insert. Remove the count column from the master table and this problem goes away.

Comment: *Remove the count column from the master table and this problem goes away* Yes; it will remove problem while insert and will reappear while reading. Master table also have huge records. I need to display paged list of master with details count. Anyway, I think I should measure the read performance after removing that column as you suggested. Thanks...

Comment: You could ask a new question showing the root problem you need solved - how to present a page of results including a count of details, presumably sorted in some way. I can't imagine computing the detail count for *one page* will stress your SQL Server much. Be sure to include a representative schema and some sample data in your new question. See [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Rather than update the materialized count column in the master table as rows are inserted/deleted in the detail table, you could create a view to aggregate the value along with an index on the view to materialize the count. The count will be maintained as rows are inserted and deleted without additional code and transactionally consistent as well. The script below uses this technique with a computed column in the master table that gets the count from the view via a scalar function.

Sessions modifying indexed view data need to have [required SET options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions). The `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` and `ANSI_NULLS` settings for procedures, views, functions, and triggers are sometimes problematic because these persisted with the object and used at runtime to override session settings. Ensure objects are created with those settings `ON`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MasterTable(
     MId int NOT NULL IDENTITY 
        CONSTRAINT PK_MasterTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.DetailsTable(
     MId int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_DetailsTable_MasterTable
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.MasterTable(MId)
    ,DId int NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_DetailsTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(MId, DId)
);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_MasterTable_DetailsCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT MId, COUNT_BIG(*) AS DetailsCount
FROM dbo.DetailsTable
GROUP BY MId;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_MasterTable_DetailsCount_MId ON dbo.vw_MasterTable_DetailsCount(MId);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_MasterTable_DetailsCount(@MId int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT DetailsCount
    FROM dbo.vw_MasterTable_DetailsCount WITH(NOEXPAND)
    WHERE MId = @Mid
);
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MasterTable
    ADD DetailsTable AS dbo.fn_MasterTable_DetailsCount(MId);
GO

--insert 1000 MasterTable
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MasterTable ON;
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t1m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b)
INSERT INTO dbo.MasterTable (MId)
SELECT num
FROM t1m
WHERE num <= 1000;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MasterTable OFF;
GO
--insert 10000 DetailsTable per MasterTable
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t1m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b)
INSERT INTO dbo.DetailsTable (MId)
SELECT MId
FROM dbo.MasterTable
CROSS JOIN t1m
WHERE num <= 10000;
GO
```

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkTLN_gFo) for the below query.

```
SELECT
      MId
    , DetailsTable
FROM dbo.MasterTable AS s
WHERE s.MId = 1;
GO
```

Be aware that the scalar function will prevent parallelism for queries referencing the master table.

I'll add that the computed column in the master table isn't required, although it does avoid the need for an explicit join/subquery in `SELECT statements`. If you don't mind additional coding to get the aggregated count, your queries could benefit from parallelism by not using the computed column/function:

```
--get materialized count from view using subquery
SELECT 
      m.MId
    , (SELECT DetailsCount FROM dbo.vw_MasterTable_DetailsCount AS d WITH(NOEXPAND) WHERE d.MId = m.MId) AS DetailsCount
FROM dbo.MasterTable AS m
WHERE m.MId = 1;

--this uses the index view in Enterprise Edition
SELECT 
      m.MId
    , (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS DetailsCount FROM dbo.DetailsTable AS d WHERE d.MId = m.MId) AS DetailsCount
FROM dbo.MasterTable AS m
WHERE m.MId = 1;
```

Comment: There will be more overhead during inserts to maintain the indexed view. It's pay now (during insert) or pay later (with manual update). If performance is especially important, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions of SQL Server such as 2012 and above, Microsoft introduced the feature of [Columnstore Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16). They persist the data in a columnar-like format (as opposed to the classic rowstore index which stores rows in the nodes of a B-Tree data structure). They are typically ideal for aggregative type of queries.

Columnstore indexes have two main benefits:

1. Data compression up & down the columns(s) it's defined on (as opposed to row or table compression), which may yield a better compression ratio.
2. [Batch Mode Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#batch-mode-execution) which allows multiple groups of data to be processed concurrently.

From the same aforementioned docs:

> Reasons why columnstore indexes are so fast:
>
> - Columns store values from the same domain and commonly have similar values, which result in high compression rates. I/O bottlenecks in your system are minimized or eliminated, and memory footprint is reduced significantly.
> - High compression rates improve query performance by using a smaller in-memory footprint. In turn, query performance can improve because SQL Server can perform more query and data operations in memory.
> - Batch execution improves query performance, typically by two to four times, by processing multiple rows together.
> - Queries often select only a few columns from a table, which reduces total I/O from the physical media.

---

Leveraging columnstore indexes in your case:

Create the index on your `DetailsTable`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_DetailsTable ON (MId);
```

Create a regular view that calculates the `COUNT()` like so:

```
CREATE VIEW DetailsTableCounts
AS

SELECT
    MId,
    COUNT(MId) AS DetailsCount
FROM DetailsTable;
```

---

Benefits of using a columnstore index over an indexed view here:

1. Indexed Views may require a little more overhead to maintain as the data changes and are generally best used for things that don't change frequently.
2. Indexed Views require being queried with the `NOEXPAND` hint on Standard Edition. (This isn't necessarily a bad thing, it's just an additional piece of code the developer needs to remember to use.)
3. Indexed Views can result in [data corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/find-corruption-indexed-view-dbcc-checkdb/) in rare cases.
4. Indexed Views can be [buggy sometimes](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/sql-indexes/an-indexed-view-bug-with-scalar-aggregates).
5. There are [limitations on what you can use inside of an indexed view](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/) should you ever want to evolve what the view encompasses.

---

Don't let the above drawbacks of indexed views discourage you from ever using them. Generally they work great for the right scenarios. But when there's a simpler solution to a problem, such as a columnstore index for an aggregative query (which is your use case), I prefer that approach.

Comment: Won't the columnstore have drawbacks when data is being modified a lot?

Comment: @Peter No not really (not comparable to an indexed view at least). Insert overhead is comparable enough to that of a rowstore index. The only thing to be aware of though is over time, with enough changes, the delta rowstore will grow significantly for the columnstore index. Routine (weekly, monthly, etc) columnstore index maintenance can be done to keep that in check. If such maintenance is not preformed, I believe the delta rowstore is then comparable to a rowstore index. So even without routine maintenance, it's not the end of the world for the data that ends up in the delta rowstore.